# Send the test results in JSON format to Xray

Tags: cypress, jira-rest-api, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I use Cypress for my tests and Cucumber to write them. I would like to automate sending my tests in Gherkin format to Jira. Currently, this part is functional, but I am facing difficulties in automatically sending the generated JSON file at the end of the tests. This file is crucial for determining whether the test has failed or not.

Run curl --location -X POST "https://jira.****.com/rest/raven/2.0/export/execution/json?projectKey=****&testPlanKey=****" --header "Authorization: ****" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @reports.json

Send the test results in JSON format to Xray

404null for uri: https://jira.adeo.com/rest/raven/2.0/export/execution/json?projectKey=MDV&testPlanKey=4353